# Alpine js, how to change variable from parent component in child component in js

Tags: alpine.js

Is it possible to change variable from the parent component in a child component in js script, if yes, how to do that?  The code below is just an example. Thank you all

```
<div x-data="parent">

    <div x-data="child">
    
    </div>

</div>
 
<script>
    document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
        Alpine.data('parent', () => ({
            open: false,
 
            toggle() {
                this.open = ! this.open
            }
        }))

       Alpine.data('child', () => ({
            
       // here I need to modify the 'open' variable to be true.

        }))
    })
</script>
```

The code is just an example. Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child should have access to parent `x-data` values, [as per the documentation](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/data#scope). The difference with `Alpine.data()`, is that the values are accessed with `this`:

```js
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.data('parent', () => ({
    open: false,
    toggle() {
      this.open = !this.open
    }
  }))

  Alpine.data('child', () => ({
    childToggle() {
      this.open = !this.open;
    },
  }))
})
```

```html
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div x-data="parent">
  <span x-text="String(open)"></span>
  <div x-data="child">
    <button @click="childToggle">Toggle</button>
  </div>
</div>
```